# Create a Dataframe of Difference scores between users for multiple variables

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, text

I have a large dataframe with users scores on a number of language dimensions, with a simplified version looking like the code below (I have included a dput replication data at the bottom of the post)

```
    user             Authentic   Analytic    Clout       Tone
2   Adams_Alma       0.05738848  0.7511374  0.3675847   0.95387755
3   Aguilar_Pete     0.24302974  0.7725205  0.3873588   0.79183673
4   Allred_Colin     0.11245353  0.7770701  0.7482345   0.58346939
5   Auchincloss_Jake 0.96119888  0.8020928  0.2673023   0.49765306
6   Axne_Cynthia     0.12500000  0.8644222  0.4918785   0.97112245
```

Using this data, I want to create a dataframe in which each row is the difference score of between a pair of users in the dataset, as seen below (though the actual dataframe is much larger).

```
    from        to                 diff_Authentic   diff_Analytic  diff_Clout  diff_Tone
1   Adams_Alma  Aguilar_Pete       0.9802260        0.123456       0.123456    0.123456
2   Adams_Alma  Allred_Colin       0.6193503        0.123456       0.123456    0.123456
3   Adams_Alma  Auchincloss_Jake   0.8997175        0.123456       0.123456    0.123456
4   Adams_Alma  Axne_Cynthia       0.8757062        0.123456       0.123456    0.123456
5   Adams_Alma  Baldwin_Tammy      0.9406780        0.123456       0.123456    0.123456
6   Adams_Alma  Barragán_Nanette   0.8495763        0.123456       0.123456    0.123456
7   Adams_Alma  Bass_Karen         0.8234463        0.123456       0.123456    0.123456
8   Adams_Alma  Beatty_Joyce       0.9014831        0.123456       0.123456    0.123456
9   Adams_Alma  Bennet_Michael     0.5183616        0.123456       0.123456    0.123456
10  Adams_Alma  Bera_Ami           0.8223870        0.123456       0.123456    0.123456
```

Using the code below, I am able to create a difference edgelist for one variable at a time, but my full dataframe has 90 variables I want differences for.

```
out <- with(norm_data, as.matrix(dist(setNames(norm_data$Authentic, norm_data$user))))
dif_g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix (out, mode = 'undirected', weighted = TRUE)
dif_edge_list <- as_data_frame(dif_g, 'edges')
dif_edge_list$weight <- 1 - dif_edge_list$weight
```

I would like to have a single dataframe that has the difference scores for each pair of users across all variables. I'm assuming a loop might be the solution, but I can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need any more info.

Dput Data:

```
Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output
structure(list(user = structure(1:50, .Label = c("Adams_Alma", 
"Aguilar_Pete", "Allred_Colin", "Auchincloss_Jake", "Axne_Cynthia", 
"Baldwin_Tammy", "Barragán_Nanette", "Bass_Karen", "Beatty_Joyce", 
"Bennet_Michael", "Bera_Ami", "Beyer_Donald", "Bishop_Sanford", 
"Blumenthal_Richard", "Blunt_Rochester_Lisa", "Bonamici_Suzanne", 
"Booker_Cory", "Bourdeaux_Carolyn", "Bowman_Jamaal", "Boyle_Brendan", 
"Brown_Anthony", "Brown_Sherrod", "Brownley_Julia", "Bush_Cori", 
"Bustos_Cheri", "Butterfield_George", "Cantwell_Maria", "Carbajal_Salud", 
"Cárdenas_Tony", "Cardin_Benjamin", "Carper_Thomas", "Carson_André", 
"Cartwright_Matthew", "Case_Ed", "Casey_Robert", "Casten_Sean", 
"Castor_Kathy", "Castro_Joaquin", "Chu_Judy", "Cicilline_David", 
"Clark_Katherine", "Clarke_Yvette", "Cleaver_Emanuel", "Clyburn_James", 
"Cohen_Steve", "Connolly_Gerald", "Coons_Christopher", "Cooper_Jim", 
"Correa_J", "Cortez_Masto_Catherine", "Costa_Jim", "Courtney_Joe", 
"Craig_Angie", "Crist_Charlie", "Crow_Jason", "Cuellar_Henry", 
"Davids_Sharice", "Davis_Danny", "Dean_Madeleine", "DeFazio_Peter", 
"DeGette_Diana", "DeLauro_Rosa", "DelBene_Suzan", "Delgado_Antonio", 
"Demings_Val", "DeSaulnier_Mark", "Deutch_Theodore", "Dingell_Debbie", 
"Doggett_Lloyd", "Doyle_Michael", "Duckworth_Tammy", "Durbin_Richard", 
"Escobar_Veronica", "Eshoo_Anna", "Espaillat_Adriano", "Evans_Dwight", 
"Feinstein_Dianne", "Fletcher_Lizzie", "Foster_Bill", "Frankel_Lois", 
"Gallego_Ruben", "Garamendi_John", "García_Jesús", "Garcia_Sylvia", 
"Golden_Jared", "Gomez_Jimmy", "Gonzalez_Vicente", "Gottheimer_Josh", 
"Green_Al", "Grijalva_Raúl", "Harder_Josh", "Hassan_Margaret", 
"Hayes_Jahana", "Heinrich_Martin", "Higgins_Brian", "Himes_James", 
"Hirono_Mazie", "Horsford_Steven", "Houlahan_Chrissy", "Hoyer_Steny", 
"Huffman_Jared", "Jackson_Lee_Sheila", "Jacobs_Sara", "Jayapal_Pramila", 
"Jeffries_Hakeem", "Johnson_Eddie", "Johnson_Henry", "Kaptur_Marcy", 
"Keating_William", "Kelly_Mark", "Kelly_Robin", "Khanna_Ro", 
"Kildee_Daniel", "Kilmer_Derek", "Kim_Andy", "Kind_Ron", "Kirkpatrick_Ann", 
"Klobuchar_Amy", "Krishnamoorthi_Raja", "Kuster_Ann", "Lamb_Conor", 
"Langevin_James", "Larsen_Rick", "Larson_John", "Lawrence_Brenda", 
"Lawson_Al", "Leahy_Patrick", "Lee_Barbara", "Lee_Susie", "Leger_Fernandez_Teresa", 
"Levin_Andy", "Levin_Mike", "Lieu_Ted", "Lofgren_Zoe", "Lowenthal_Alan", 
"Luján_Ben", "Luria_Elaine", "Lynch_Stephen", "Malinowski_Tom", 
"Maloney_Carolyn", "Maloney_Sean", "Manchin_Joe", "Manning_Kathy", 
"Markey_Edward", "Matsui_Doris", "McBath_Lucy", "McCollum_Betty", 
"McEachin_A", "McGovern_James", "McNerney_Jerry", "Meeks_Gregory", 
"Menendez_Robert", "Meng_Grace", "Merkley_Jeff", "Mfume_Kweisi", 
"Moore_Gwen", "Morelle_Joseph", "Moulton_Seth", "Mrvan_Frank", 
"Murphy_Stephanie", "Murray_Patty", "Nadler_Jerrold", "Napolitano_Grace", 
"Neal_Richard", "Neguse_Joe", "Newman_Marie", "Norcross_Donald", 
"Norton_Eleanor", "O_Halleran_Tom", "Ocasio_Cortez_Alexandria", 
"Omar_Ilhan", "Ossoff_Jon", "Padilla_Alejandro", "Pallone_Frank", 
"Panetta_Jimmy", "Pappas_Chris", "Pascrell_Bill", "Payne_Donald", 
"Pelosi_Nancy", "Perlmutter_Ed", "Peters_Gary", "Peters_Scott", 
"Phillips_Dean", "Pingree_Chellie", "Plaskett_Stacey", "Pocan_Mark", 
"Porter_Katie", "Pressley_Ayanna", "Price_David", "Quigley_Mike", 
"Raskin_Jamie", "Reed_John", "Rice_Kathleen", "Rosen_Jacky", 
"Ross_Deborah", "Roybal_Allard_Lucille", "Ruiz_Raul", "Ruppersberger_C", 
"Rush_Bobby", "Ryan_Tim", "Sablan_Gregorio", "Sánchez_Linda", 
"Sarbanes_John", "Scanlon_Mary", "Schakowsky_Janice", "Schatz_Brian", 
"Schiff_Adam", "Schneider_Bradley", "Schrader_Kurt", "Schrier_Kim", 
"Schumer_Charles", "Scott_David", "Scott_Robert", "Sewell_Terri", 
"Shaheen_Jeanne", "Shelby_Richard", "Sherman_Brad", "Sherrill_Mikie", 
"Sinema_Kyrsten", "Sires_Albio", "Slotkin_Elissa", "Smith_Adam", 
"Smith_Tina", "Soto_Darren", "Spanberger_Abigail", "Speier_Jackie", 
"Stabenow_Debbie", "Stanton_Greg", "Stevens_Haley", "Strickland_Marilyn", 
"Suozzi_Thomas", "Swalwell_Eric", "Takano_Mark", "Tester_Jon", 
"Thompson_Bennie", "Thompson_Mike", "Titus_Dina", "Tlaib_Rashida", 
"Tonko_Paul", "Torres_Norma", "Torres_Ritchie", "Trahan_Lori", 
"Trone_David", "Underwood_Lauren", "user", "Van_Hollen_Chris", 
"Vargas_Juan", "Veasey_Marc", "Vela_Filemon", "Velázquez_Nydia", 
"Warner_Mark", "Warnock_Raphael", "Warren_Elizabeth", "Wasserman_Schultz_Debbie", 
"Waters_Maxine", "Watson_Coleman_Bonnie", "Welch_Peter", "Wexton_Jennifer", 
"Whitehouse_Sheldon", "Wild_Susan", "Williams_Nikema", "Wilson_Frederica", 
"Wyden_Ron", "Yarmuth_John"), class = "factor"), Authentic = c(0.0573884758364312, 
0.243029739776952, 0.112453531598513, 0.961198884758364, 0.125, 
0.139869888475836, 0.131737918215613, 0.174024163568773, 0.115706319702602, 
0.325046468401487, 0.223048327137546, 0.087592936802974, 0.133364312267658, 
0.190985130111524, 0.21003717472119, 0.0422862453531598, 0.153113382899628, 
0.263708178438662, 0.157295539033457, 0.328996282527881, 0.139637546468401, 
0.48025092936803, 0.26974907063197, 0.378020446096654, 0.153113382899628, 
0.454693308550186, 0.0820167286245353, 0.130576208178439, 0.33317843866171, 
0.263243494423792, 0.197490706319703, 0.295074349442379, 0.251626394052045, 
0.303671003717472, 0.180065055762082, 0.155204460966543, 0.10246282527881, 
0.237453531598513, 0.132434944237918, 0.151022304832714, 0.10339219330855, 
0.991635687732342, 0.185176579925651, 0.263475836431227, 0.0669144981412639, 
0.143587360594796, 0.127788104089219, 0.212360594795539, 0.45817843866171, 
0.054135687732342), Analytic = c(0.751137397634213, 0.772520473157416, 
0.777070063694267, 0.802092811646951, 0.86442220200182, 0.75796178343949, 
0.847133757961783, 0.873976342129208, 0.816196542311192, 0.801182893539581, 
0.809827115559599, 0.695177434030937, 0.803457688808007, 0.726569608735214, 
0.774795268425842, 0.843039126478617, 0.788898999090082, 0.773885350318471, 
0.79936305732484, 0.78434940855323, 0.939945404913557, 0.772520473157416, 
0.741128298453139, 0.736123748862602, 0.927206551410373, 0.673794358507734, 
0.859872611464968, 0.763421292083712, 0.810282074613285, 0.871701546860782, 
0.834849863512284, 0.786624203821656, 0.782984531392174, 1, 0.872611464968152, 
0.748862602365787, 0.804367606915377, 0.79936305732484, 0.682893539581438, 
0.761601455868971, 0.722929936305732, 0.767970882620564, 0.845313921747043, 
0.79663330300273, 0.74294813466788, 0.840764331210191, 0.894904458598726, 
0.787534121929026, 0.800272975432211, 0.883530482256597), Clout = c(0.367584745762712, 
0.387358757062147, 0.748234463276836, 0.267302259887006, 0.491878531073446, 
0.426906779661017, 0.518008474576271, 0.191031073446328, 0.466101694915254, 
0.849223163841808, 0.545197740112994, 0.475988700564972, 0.548728813559322, 
0.711511299435028, 0.538841807909604, 0.792372881355932, 0.49364406779661, 
0.487641242937853, 0.64795197740113, 0.370409604519774, 0.771186440677966, 
0.288488700564972, 0.211158192090395, 0.273658192090395, 0.420197740112994, 
1, 0.531779661016949, 0.629237288135593, 0.646539548022599, 0.208686440677966, 
0.189618644067797, 0.92090395480226, 0.632415254237288, 0.965042372881356, 
0.34180790960452, 0.392302259887005, 0.604166666666666, 0.548375706214689, 
0.401836158192091, 0.415254237288136, 0.364759887005649, 0.332980225988701, 
0.354519774011299, 0.346398305084746, 0.52295197740113, 0.453389830508474, 
0.777189265536723, 0.332980225988701, 0.436087570621469, 0.387358757062147
), Tone = c(0.953877551020408, 0.791836734693877, 0.583469387755102, 
0.49765306122449, 0.971122448979592, 0.994183673469388, 0.626836734693878, 
0.893061224489796, 0.34469387755102, 0.68530612244898, 0.970204081632653, 
0.698265306122449, 0.959795918367347, 0.379183673469388, 0.988469387755102, 
0.930408163265306, 0.0593877551020408, 0.744897959183674, 0.884387755102041, 
0.803367346938776, 0.659285714285714, 0.422244897959184, 0.283571428571429, 
0.252755102040816, 0.926530612244898, 0.988265306122449, 0.76469387755102, 
0.525408163265306, 0.817040816326531, 0.891428571428571, 0.81265306122449, 
0.451632653061224, 0.654285714285714, 0.727244897959184, 0.974591836734694, 
0.467448979591837, 0.798775510204082, 0.501122448979592, 0.919795918367347, 
0.744897959183674, 0.83234693877551, 0.931224489795918, 0.866326530612245, 
0.448673469387755, 0.766530612244898, 0.326734693877551, 0.847959183673469, 
0.685204081632653, 0.78765306122449, 0.847755102040816)), row.names = 2:51, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid repetition and thus not using O(N^2), i would prefer using vectorized methods. We know that we need 1-2,1-3.. etc and these are the same as 2-1,3-1, upto the sign constant. We could do:

```
index <- which(lower.tri(diag(nrow(df))), T)

a <- data.frame(user1 = df[index[,2],1],
      user2 = df[index[,1],1], 
      diff = df[index[,2],-1] - df[index[,1],-1], row.names = NULL)

      user1            user2 diff.Authentic diff.Analytic  diff.Clout   diff.Tone
1 Adams_Alma     Aguilar_Pete    -0.18564126  -0.021383076 -0.01977401  0.16204082
2 Adams_Alma     Allred_Colin    -0.05506506  -0.025932666 -0.38064972  0.37040816
3 Adams_Alma Auchincloss_Jake    -0.90381041  -0.050955414  0.10028249  0.45622449
4 Adams_Alma     Axne_Cynthia    -0.06761152  -0.113284804 -0.12429379 -0.01724490
5 Adams_Alma    Baldwin_Tammy    -0.08248141  -0.006824386 -0.05932203 -0.04030612
6 Adams_Alma Barragán_Nanette    -0.07434944  -0.095996360 -0.15042373  0.32704082
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(data, user2 = data$user) %>%
  filter(user != user2) %>%
  left_join(data, by = c("user2" = "user")) %>%
  transmute(
    from = user,
    to = user2,
    Authentic_diff = Authentic.y - Authentic.x,
    Analytic_diff =  Analytic.y - Analytic.x,
    Clout_diff = Clout.y - Clout.x,
    Tone_diff = Tone.y - Tone.x
    
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# set as data.table
setDT(df)

# as.character (needed to rid permutation)
df[, user := as.character(user)]

# cross join
df_1 <- df[, as.list(df), names(df)]

# name change
x <- unlist(lapply(list('x.', 'i.'), \(i) paste0(i, names(df))))
names(df_1) <- x

# rid combo from replacement. Change to != for permutation
df_1 <- df_1[i.user < x.user]

# names net prefix
y <- gsub('x\\.|i\\.', '', x)

# construct formula
z <- lapply(2:5, \(i) paste0('diff_', y[i], '=', x[i], '-', x[i+5]))
a <- paste('.(' ,paste(unlist(z), collapse=','), ')')

# calculate diff
df_1[, eval(parse(text=a))]
```

and my personal fav. Benchmarking :)

```
# benchmark
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.table(user = 1:10000)
df[, `:=` (Authentic = user
           , Analytic = user
           , Clout = user
           , Tone = user
           )]
df[, user := as.character(user)]


xx <-
microbenchmark(sweepydodo = {
                              # cross join
                              df_1 <- df[, as.list(df), names(df)]
                              
                              # name change
                              x <- unlist(lapply(list('x.', 'i.'), \(i) paste0(i, names(df))))
                              names(df_1) <- x
                              
                              # rid combo from replacement. Change to != for permutation
                              df_1 <- df_1[i.user > x.user]
                              
                              # names net prefix
                              y <- gsub('x\\.|i\\.', '', x)
                              
                              # construct formula
                              z <- lapply(2:5, \(i) paste0('diff_', y[i], '=', x[i], '-', x[i+5]))
                              a <- paste('.(' ,paste(unlist(z), collapse=','), ')')
                              
                              # calculate diff
                              df_1[, eval(parse(text=a))]
                              }
               , Onyambu = {
                            index <- which(lower.tri(diag(nrow(df))), T)
                            a <- data.frame(user1 = df[index[,2],1]
                                            , user2 = df[index[,1],1] 
                                            , diff = df[index[,2],-1] - df[index[,1],-1]
                                            , row.names = NULL
                                            )
                            }
               , Onyambu_modified = {
                                      x <- 1:nrow(df)
                                      index <- CJ(a=x,b=x)[a>b]
                                      a <- data.table(user1 = df[index[[2]],1]
                                                      , user2 = df[index[[1]],1] 
                                                      , diff = df[index[[2]],-1] - df[index[[1]],-1]
                                                      , row.names = NULL
                                                      )
                                      }
               , Iman = {
                          crossing(df, user2 = df$user) %>%
                            filter(user != user2) %>%
                            left_join(df, by = c("user2" = "user")) %>%
                            transmute(from = user,
                                        to = user2,
                                        Authentic_diff = Authentic.y - Authentic.x,
                                        Analytic_diff =  Analytic.y - Analytic.x,
                                        Clout_diff = Clout.y - Clout.x,
                                        Tone_diff = Tone.y - Tone.x
                                      )
                 }
               , times = 30
               )

# plot
autoplot(xx)
```

[image: benchmarking]

Comment: @Onyambu very cool idea to use a triangular matrix's index to get combinations. I tweaked it to squeeze better run time. New benchmark above now uses a `df` with 1e4 rows instead of OP's 50 rows.

@Iman if wanted please let me know how to tweak yours to get combination (it is currently permutation)

I noticed my original solution performs the poorest on the now larger `df` :(